# Deleting records from Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have 2 tables in my database: `Car` and `Garage`

where `Car` and `Garage` are connected via foreign keys with each other:

In `Car`, the foreign key is `carHasGarages`. The whole schema looks like:

```
Destination: Garage
Inverse: `garageHasCar`
Delete rule: `Cascade`
Type: `To Many`
```

In `Garage` the foreign key is `garageHasCar` and the schema is:

```
Destination: Car
Inverse: `carHasGarage`
Delete rule: `Nullify`
Type: `To Many`
```

When I try to batch delete my `garages` by using the predicate:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "carNbr IN %@", inactiveCars)

let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Car")
request.predicate = predicate
let batchDelete = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: request)

do {
    try context.execute(batchDelete)
}...
```

where `inactiveCars` is the array of `[Int32]`

I get the next error:

```
error: Unhandled error from executeBatchDeleteRequest Constraint
violation: Batch delete failed due to mandatory MTM nullify inverse on Garage/garageHasCar and userInfo {
"_NSCoreDataOptimisticLockingFailureConflictsKey" =     (
    "<null>"
);
}
```

Can someone point to my mistake? I'm trying to solve this problem 2 days already and cannot manage it. So I thought maybe I do not see anything or miss something.
Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Why is your delete rule `Cascade`?  Deleting a single car shouldn't delete the garage.  Also, why is it "to many"?  Surely a car can only be in at most one garage at a time?  Your garage->car should be to-many as a garage can have more than one car.  In both cases the delete rule should probably  be "nullify"

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsbatchdeleterequest), this request is directly called on the backing store (most probably you are using sqlite here). Since the core data framework layer isn't much involved here, it looks like your deletion is leaving your sqlite in a bad state.

My guess on bad state: all inactive cars are deleted, but the garages still hold a reference to them since their relationship wasn't handled.